# Error running Q# notebooks: Syntax does not match any known patterns

Tags: q#

[image: Q]

C:/snippet_.qs(1,85): error QS3001: Syntax does not match any known patterns.
C:/snippet_.qs(1,26): error QS6104: No namespace with the name "Microsoft.Quantum.Intrinsic" exists.
C:/snippet_.qs(7,17): error QS5022: No identifier with the name "ArcSin" exists.
C:/snippet_.qs(7,30): error QS5022: No identifier with the name "Sqrt" exists.
C:/snippet_.qs(8,5): error QS5022: No identifier with the name "Ry" exists.
C:/snippet_.qs(11,25): error QS5022: No identifier with the name "H" exists.

Answer (score 2):

You can see in the output of the first cell that the versions of packages `Microsoft.Quantum.Standard` and `Microsoft.Quantum.Katas` do not match; they have to match for you to be able to use `%kata` command that invokes unit test (the first line of the second cell).

1. If you want to run the Katas (and run unit tests on your code), you need to update your local installation of IQ# to match the version used in `%package` command. All katas have instructions on how to update IQ# to a specific version, or you can use [these instructions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/quantum/install-guide/update#update-iq-for-jupyter-notebooks).
2. If you want to run Q# notebooks without the katas, just to run some Q# code, you need to remove the first cell and the `%kata` command from the second cell.

Comment: gracias!  grateful